# Is it possible to set AppInsights instrumentation key at runtime within an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Normally, the instrumentation key for AppInsights is set within the `IConfiguration` in a key called `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`.  This might appear in your appsettings.json file, or in an environment variable, or anything else an `IConfigurationBuilder` supports.  However, what if one wanted to set the instrumentation key at runtime.  This is what I expect should work:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    // Test code
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
    {
        InstrumentationKey = "461df8ba-af74-444b-a896-f47c5c6dd02d",
        DeveloperMode = true
    });

    // ... Various configuration stuff
}
```

When I do this, I can verify that a `TelemetryClient` is injected into the constructor of my function classes, and I can verify the right instrumentation key was set:

[image]

These telemetry items even show up in the local debugger window, so I know the client is processing them:

[image]

However, I wait and I wait and they never actually show up in AppInsights.  When I put the same instrumentation key in my local settings JSON, everything works perfectly.

Does anyone have a good example showing how to set the AppInsights key at runtime and NOT use `IConfiguration`.  Thanks!

### Update:

Dug through some [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), and it looks like calling `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` will conflict with the out of the box AppInsights services:

[image]

So, I might be out of luck.  I'll keep this question open for a bit though, in case anyone has a work around.  BTW, the reason I'm asking is my team is building a framework to configure all microservices in a consistent way.  Some of our microservices use Azure Functions, so if the standard configuration calls don't work, we'll need to indicate this in the documentation or perhaps throw an exception or something.

Comment: what about using `ILogger<T>` everywhere? Any specific need to use `TelmetryClient` unless you are not using Metic or Event telemetry? Another suggestion can be exposed the `TelemetryClient` via wrapper and inject by `ILoggingProvider`

Comment: @user1672994 We want the internal telemetry events, such as `Requests` to go to a specific AppInsights resource.  We also use custom metrics and events.  It doesn't appear it's possible to programmatically set the instrumentation key regardless.  The wrapper approach would possibly work for custom telemetry events, but yea you'd basically be duplicating everything Azure Functions does internally..

Comment: @MikeChristensen please see answer below and let me know if it can work for you.

Comment: @IvanYang Yup I plan on trying it out today.  I had removed all the code since I deemed it wasn't possible to do, so I'll have to add it back in to test..

Answer (score 1):

Please try install this package [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/).

Then in your Startup.cs, the code looks like below:

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {            
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            return new TelemetryConfiguration("put the instrumentation key here");
        });
    }
```

Then in the function, use `TelemetryClient` to send data:

```
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    public Function1(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace("11 track trace 2222...");
    }
```

Comment: Gave this a shot and it doesn't quite work.  I can create telemetry events directly off the injected `TelemetryClient` singleton such as custom events and custom traces (as shown above), but internal telemetry such as "Requests" no longer work.  Traces created through the `ILogger` also no longer work.  So, with this solution you'd then be responsible for handling 100% of AppInsights telemetry using custom code.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I just want to confirm, do you want to send some logs into appinsights_1, and send some logs to another appinsights_2?

Comment: Nope, I want to send ALL logs (traces, requests, etc) to the same AppInsights instance, however I want to provide the instrumentation key with code, not in an appsettings JSON file.  I want there to be one TelemetryClient singleton that's used internally by the function host as well as via dependency injection.

Comment: @MikeChristensen try to add another line of code `builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights("xxx");
            });` to see if it can do the trick.

Comment: Closer!  This fixes the log events (both internal and written through ILogger<T>), I still get nothing in the *requests* table though..